# Multiple markers trackable augmented reality android application

Tags: android, augmented-reality, qcar-sdk

I am using qualcomm sdk for creating augmented reality on android phones.
I am able to use the ImageTargets sample application to check the trackable and then 
initiate an intent to call another activity when that marker comes in screen.
I figured out that when the marker is sensed by the QCAR sdk then the control is in on resume.
So then i navigate the user to another activity.

My problem is that i have 5 markers and in onResume or any place i must have a switch case to get the ID of the markers in order to do different tasks on different markers.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `Trackable` object in ImageTargets.cpp has a method `getName()`, so you can call `trackable->getName()` to get the name of the current marker and return it to your Java code for further use.